# Opencv flood fill filling outside region

Tags: opencv

I have been experimenting with the opencv flood fill, and seem to be missing something.

While working on solving another problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433662/display-regions-detected-by-cvpyrsegmentation-in-opencv) I created a simple test application to work with flood fill:

```
void addRect(cv::Mat image, cv::Point start, cv::Scalar color, int height, int width)
{
    cv::Size size(width, height);
    cv::Rect rect(start, size);

    cv::rectangle(image, rect, color, CV_FILLED );
}

void fillImage(cv::Mat image, cv::Point start, cv::Point end, cv::Scalar fill, cv::Scalar maskColor)
{
    cv::Rect area(cv::Point(start.x, start.y), cv::Point(end.x, end.y) );                

    cv::Mat mask(image.rows + 2, image.cols + 2, CV_8UC1, cvScalar(0) );              
    cv::rectangle(image, area, cvScalar(1), CV_FILLED );

    cv::floodFill(image, mask, start, fill);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("This is a test application to test the floodFill function in opencv.\n");
    cv::Mat baseImage(512, 512, CV_8UC3, cvScalar(0,0,0) );

    addRect(baseImage, cv::Point(50,50), cvScalar(0,0,255), 100, 100);

    cv::Mat fillImageHit = baseImage.clone();

    fillImage(fillImageHit, cv::Point(55, 100), cv::Point(200,200), cvScalar(255,0,0), cvScalar(0,0,255) );

    cvNamedWindow("Base Image");
    cv::imshow("Base Image", baseImage);

    cvNamedWindow("Hit Fill Image");
    cv::imshow("Hit Fill Image", fillImageHit);

    cvWaitKey(0);

    cvDestroyWindow("Base Image");
    cvDestroyWindow("Hit Fill Image");
}
```

It's pretty basic, but the full mask area is filled; the fill does not end at the edge of the rectangle. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of input the whole image for floodfill, use a rect-area:

```
void fillImage(cv::Mat image, cv::Point start, cv::Point end, cv::Scalar fill, cv::Scalar maskColor)
{
    cv::Rect area(cv::Point(start.x, start.y), cv::Point(end.x, end.y) );                

    cv::Mat mask(image.rows + 2, image.cols + 2, CV_8UC1, cvScalar(0) );              
    cv::rectangle(image, area, cvScalar(1), CV_FILLED );

    cv::floodFill(cv::Mat(image,area), cv::Mat(mask,area) , start, fill);
}
```

I do not have the enviroment set up here, but I think it should work!